# Idea says "The JavaFX runtime is not configured. Either use a JDK that has the JavaFX built in, or add a JavaFX library to the classpath"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-9, java-10

I recently installed Java 10. The JavaFX project I opened runs with Java 8, and its "Project SDK" and "Project language level" in Idea are both set to use JDK 8, and Java 8 includes the jfxrt.jar file where it's supposed to be (jre/lib/ext). I can build and run the project on the command line with Gradle without issue.

If I modify how Idea starts up to use Java 8, Idea doesn't complain.

So... is this a bug? I'm not up on the new dependency tree stuff, but shouldn't Idea declare JavaFX as a dependency if it needs it? Clearly the project I'm working on is set up fine.

Comment: Well, some error message or actual code in question could have helped understand what you've tried to explain theoretically mostly.

Comment: The java -version output would be useful too as Oracle JDK 10 builds include the Java FX modules, the OpenJDK builds of JDK 10 do not.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the [steps on the openjfx website to add JavaFX to IntelliJ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction) (look under the JavaFX and IntelliJ section on the left-hand menu).

1. Install JavaFX from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)
2. Navigate to File -> Project Settings
3. Install SDK 19
4. On the Libraries tab, add the JavaFX 19 SDK as a library to the project